# Handling comma in string values in a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a comma-separated file which has numeric and string columns. String columns are quoted and can have comma in between the quotes. How do I identify the columns with `FS =","`?

Sample records

```
"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"
```

In [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) it should be

```
$1 = "prabhat,kumar"
$2 = 19
$3 = "2000"
$4 = "bangalore,india"
```

Setting `FS=","` is creating the problem.

Input is:

```
"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India","ABC,DEF","GHI",123,"KLM","NOP,QRS"
"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India","ABC,DEF","GHI",123,"KLM","NOP,QRS"
```

Output should be:

```
"prabhat,kumar"|19|2000|"bangalore,India"|"ABC,DEF"|"GHI"|123|"KLM"|"NOP,QRS"
"prabhat,kumar"|19|2000|"bangalore,India"|"ABC,DEF"|"GHI"|123|"KLM"|"NOP,QRS"
```

Code I am trying:

```
awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(i%NF==0){ORS="\n"} {if($i ~ /^\"/ || $i ~ /\"$/) {a=a OFS $i;j++;{if(j%2==0){sub(/^\,/,X,a); print a;j=0;a=""}}} else {print $i}}} {ORS="|"}}' ORS="|" OFS=, p.txt
```

Comment: And that is why you should use a proper library that parses CSV (and XML and HTML etc.) rather than trying to write your own. Take a look at [CSVfix](http://neilb.bitbucket.org/csvfix/)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should use a proper CSV parser. For example, in Perl, you can use `Text::CSV`:

1. Install `cpanm` (if you use Perl, you'll thank me later)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install cpanminus
   ```

   If you're not on a Debian based system, you should be able to install it using your distribution's package manager.
2. Install the `Text::CSV` module

   ```
   $ sudo cpanm Text::CSV
   ```
3. Parse your file

   ```
   $ perl -MText::CSV -le '
       $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary=>1}); 
       while ($row = $csv->getline(STDIN)){
       print "1:$row->[0], 2:$row->[1], 3:$row->[2], 4:$row->[3]"}' < file.csv 
   1:prabhat,kumar, 2:19, 3:2000, 4:bangalore,India
   ```

   As you can see above, the 1st field is `$row->[0]`, the second `$row->[1]` etc.

---

That was the correct way. A simpler, but dirty, hack would be to replace any quoted commas with another character. Then, use `awk` normally and finally, switch them back to commas again. I am using `###` here but you can use anything you are sure will never be in one of your fields.

```
$ sed -r 's/("[^",]+),([^",]+")/\1###\2/g' file.csv | 
    awk -F, '{print $1,$3}' | sed 's/###/,/g'
"prabhat,kumar" 2000
```

Comment: Your script has a problem if the quoted field doesn't contain a comma.`echo '"prabhat kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"'|sed -r 's/("[^"]+),([^"]+")/\1###\2/g'` prints
`"prabhat kumar",19###2000,"bangalore,India"`

Comment: First field in the above should be `"prabhat kumar"` - sorry

Comment: I cut the wrong line:
 `echo '"prabhat kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"'| sed -r 's/("[^"]+),([^"]+")/\1###\2/g'` prints `"prabhat kumar",19###2000,"bangalore,India"`

Comment: @DougO'Neal yeah, I see the problem, thanks. I don't have time to fix it right now but anyway, as I said, that's just a dirty hack and a proper parser should be used instead.

Comment: OP asked for awk

Comment: @andrew, first of all it is standard practice on this site to offer answers using different tools, especially when the OP is using the wrong tool for the job. Remember that our objective is to provide answers that help future users as well as the OP. In any case, the OP did not actually ask for awk, they just happen to have tried awk first.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{ gsub("^\"|\"$","",$1); gsub("^\"|\"$","",$4); print $1 $4} '
prabhat,kumarbangalore,India
```

The output format is a little ugly as I've only printed `$1` and `$4` next to each other - I'm sure you can alter it to your taste.

If you need to retain the double quotes around the fields, remove both `gsub();` functions.

#### Explanation:

Normally, `awk` separates fields in a record by the content of the  `FS` (Field Separator) variable, which defaults to any whitespace (tab, space and newline). The separator tells `awk` where a record ends. In a `csv` file, a record ends at a comma (passed to `awk` as `-vFS=,`), but of course, in examples similar to yours, this is too simple and it breaks.

Alternatively, the `FPAT` (Field Pattern) defines the record within `awk`. Instead of telling `awk` where the record ends, you create a definition that encompasses a whole record. In the complex `csv` of your example, this is `[^,]*|"[^"]*"`

This breaks down as follows:-

- Characters that are not commas (`[^,]`) as many times as possible (`*`). Everything between two commas is a field.
- Or (`|`)
- A single double-quote (`"`) followed by no double-quotes (`[^"]`) as many times as possible (`*`) followed by a single double-quote (`"`). Everything within double-quotes (including a comma) counts as one field.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is handy for CSV parsing:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), :col_sep=>"|")' file
```

```
prabhat,kumar|19|2000|bangalore,India|ABC,DEF|GHI|123|KLM|NOP,QRS
prabhat,kumar|19|2000|bangalore,India|ABC,DEF|GHI|123|KLM|NOP,QRS
```

Note that there are no quotes in the outputs. This is because none of the fields contain the field separator. If you need quotes, you can forcibly quote all fields (even integers):

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'puts CSV.generate_line(CSV.parse_line($_), :col_sep=>"|",:force_quotes=>true)' file
```

```
"prabhat,kumar"|"19"|"2000"|"bangalore,India"|"ABC,DEF"|"GHI"|"123"|"KLM"|"NOP,QRS"
"prabhat,kumar"|"19"|"2000"|"bangalore,India"|"ABC,DEF"|"GHI"|"123"|"KLM"|"NOP,QRS"
```

Comment: OP asked for awk

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` instead:

```
$ echo '"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"' |
  perl -F',(?![[:alpha:]])' -anle 'print "$F[0] $F[3]"'
"prabhat,kumar" "bangalore,India"
```

Comment: Clever! However, it will fail for cases where there is a non letter after the comma. For example `prabhat, (kumar)` or a letter after a non-quoted comma: `"prabhat,kumar",A 19,`

Comment: @terdon: Yes, of course, as it's desired. Your answer using `Text:CSV` is better for this job.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ echo '"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"' | 
  awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'| 
    awk -F\" '{print $2,$3,$4}'|awk -F\  '{print $1","$2,$3,$4,$5","$6}'`
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer

Comment: This will only work if you know the format before hand. What if it is the 3d field that's quoted and not the 1st?

Comment: OP gave a specific format, no need nor expectation for the format to change. "Last,First",Age,Year,"City,Country".  Bangalore is a city in Karnataka, so state is undefined in the data.  First and fourth field are text, let's expect quotes.  Second and third field is integer and would/should never be quoted. Understand the data and avoid over complicating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a qsv would be more your speed?

```
sed 's/.*/,&,/;:t
s/,"/"/;s/",/"/;s/,\([^"]*\),/"\1/;tt
' <<\DATA
"prabhat,kumar",19,2000,"bangalore,India"
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
"prabhat,kumar"19"2000"bangalore,India"
```